# An efficient match_chk/2 predicate in Prolog

Tags: prolog, matching

I want to check two terms if they are matchable by `=/2`, and during the checking no variable should be bound.

For example: `match_chk/2`

```
| ?- match_chk(X, a).
true. % without any binding
```

This can be done by using asymmetric [subsumes_term/2](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=subsumes_term/2) twice but this seems inefficient since might need to scan terms 2 times.

```
match_chk(A, B) :-
    ( subsumes_term(A, B)
    ; subsumes_term(B, A)
    ), !.
```

Comment: Not valid a simple?: \+ ( A \= B )

Comment: Do you want that `match_chk(X+Y,Y+X), match_chk(X+b,a+Y)` fails? It is not clear what you mean by "matchable". There are, actually, several concurring definitions (three come immediately to my mind) of what "matching" might be.

Comment: ... actually, four different meanings ...

Comment: Sorry, I meant  a default `=/2` matching of prolog. I added it to the post.

Comment: @pasaba por aqui, you could write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Prolog implements negation as *negation as failure*, when a `\+ Goal` succeeds, no bindings are returned. As you want to know if two terms are *unifiable*, you can then simple use **double negation**:

```
unifiable(Term1, Term2) :-
    \+ \+ Term1 = Term2.
```

Or, if you prefer, as in @passaba por aqui comment:

```
unifiable(Term1, Term2) :-
    \+ Term1 \= Term2.
```